# Rails transactions with find_or_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app, I have a form that submits data to two different models `booking.rb` and `guest.rb`. Each model must validate their respective data and only if both are valid should the rest of the script continue.

I believe transactions are the way forward with this and in fact I have another scenario in the same app where I do use a transaction.

However, with this scenario the @guest instance is generated using:

```
@guest = Guest.find_or_create_by(:email => params[:email])
```

and of course, this line will actually create the record if it doesn't exist. My understanding is that a transaction will not rollback if it is actually created? Ideally what I need is something like:

```
@guest = Guest.find_or_new(:email => params[:email])
```

but I don't think this is an option in Rails?

I could then go on and perform the transaction and rollback if there was a validation error:

```
begin
  @booking.transaction do
    @booking.save!
    @guest.save!
  end
  redirect_to somewhere
rescue
  render :new
end
```

**My question** How can I validate the two models using a transaction whilst also taking into account the `find_or_create_by` ?

Comment: Which database do you use? (SQLite, PostgreSQL, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything done in a transaction is reverted if the transaction is rolled back. (Well, almost everthing, there are some vendor-specific pitfalls)

That also is true for `find_or_create` as long as it is called **during the transaction**. After a rollback the created object is still around in memory, but the backing database row no longer exists.

So as long as your code looks like this you should be safe:

```
Booking.transaction do
  @guest = Guest.find_or_create_by(:email => params[:email])

  @booking.save!
  @guest.save!
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is necessary, doesn't finde and create call call save under the hood?

Comment: I think the idea here @DrewVerlee is that by doing save!  ( with a bang ! ) it forces the save. Using "!" still doesn't work for me though..... when I call a find_or_create in the middle of a bad transaction, my find_or_create is rolled back even with " save! "

Comment: The `guest.save!` call is not necessary, but it was present in the OP's example. I just kept it to visualize how the original code can be transformed into a single transaction without rewriting the whole thing (Note: one can also use `find_or_create_by!`)